# How in the web farms or cloud the actual data gets synced between the servers inside the web farm or cloud

Tags: database, cloud, data-synchronization

1- lets say the web app is hosted on some cloud like azure, aws etc.

2- and Let say a user changed his profile details on my web app...

3- i am assuming that the request with the new data will hit one of the servers/VM inside the cloud.

4- Lets say the data has got saved in sql server db hosted on the same server/VM as the request landed on ...

Now the questions ..
What i am really confused about is that ..

1- the data will be saved on one single database in the first place then how it gets synced to other servers (if it happens, i am not sure about this) instantly.. because there is no guarantee that the next request from the same user will land on the same server...

2- and if the above scenario is invalid and there exists a shared database server for all application servers inside the cloud then isn't it going to be useless as ultimately the database server is going to get overloaded ... because all the servers/VMs hosting application will be hitting the same db at once ...

i know it's a wide question and i don't know if i have explained it properly ..

but please ask me about anything which i haven't made clear ..

any help whether it is a good link explaining the insights or a series of Q&A with me, anything would be great.. as i have to design such a mechanism and i couldn't find any standard approaches or that how the market leaders are doing it ...

Comment: Belongs on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic)?

Comment: Not sure about the context of SuperUser in this case ... Not getting what do you mean ...

Comment: This question has nothing to do with Azure or AWS, or database mirroring (I removed Azure and database-mirroring tags). Also, questions asking for links to tutorials/etc. or off-topic. Not sure what point #2 is about (database server getting overloaded). This really comes down to architectural decisions. And there's plenty out there, with a simple search, to learn about using databases/caches/etc. to deal with data that must be agnostic to any particular web server.

Comment: i did add azure and AWS for examples of the fact that you can scale your app across multiple machines/VMs after deploying it ... My question arises exactly at this point that ok application has got copied over multiple VMs .. that's fine! ... what about database ? has it been copied across as well ? if yes then how will the upcoming data be distributed, synced or whatever .. across all the VMs ? like if a user has edited his profile and it got saved on one of the VMs .. how it will be shared among the other VMs ? ... i don't know if i make sense now or not :( ?

Comment: @DavidMakogon in Point#2 by 'overloaded' i mean exactly the same fact due to which anybody would scale up .. Like when there are too many requests/queries/connections for a server to handle optimally, we look forward to scale up ... it wasn't the 'overload' which we often use in programming ... sorry for the confusion ...

Comment: @perfectduffer - I meant that database scaling is a topic all of its own, and differs by database type (whether scale-out or scale-up), where each database vendor provides guidance for scaling its particular database. And solving that problem has nothing to do with running in cloud vm's vs local hardware. And database scaling does not equate to database-copying (which you alluded to in your other comment).

Comment: @DavidMakogon OK, yes.. i am sorry about that .. i call it copying but i didn't mean that ... by all of this messy question i only mean to understand that how does the applications hosted in the cloud share, sync etc. the actual data ... and if i am understanding your point correctly then .. do you mean that all these cloud providers uses the features provided by the database itself for doing all that syncing and sharing of data ?